# VBA Filldown copies the header when there is only a row of data

Tags: excel, vba

as the title says, the filldown works fine in VBA when I have more than 2 rows of data, but when I only have one row, it copies the header, why is it doing this?

```
PASsht.Range("I" & LastRow1 & ":I" & AftLastRow).FillDown
```

LastRow1 is the first row where the data is , AftLastRow is the last row where the data is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will certainly work if your `LastRow1` and `AftLastRow` keep correct numbers and in `I & LastRow1` it is a value to be filled down... Try moving the cursor over the variables when the code stops on error. What they do show? Or, insert in front of this line `Debug.Print  LastRow1, AftLastRow, PASsht.Range("I" & LastRow1).value`. What does it return in Immediate Window (`Ctrl + G` in VBE)?

Comment: how is LastRow1 and AftLastRow determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there's no hint in MS Help [FillDown method](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.range.filldown) *), in case of one single data row (i.e. the first data row equals the last data row), the FillDown method will grab the contents of above and fill it to that cell.

To avoid copying e.g. headers above you could code e.g. as follows (note the changed variable names `firstDataRow` and `lastDataRow`):

```
If firstDataRow <> lastDataRow Then PASsht.Range("I" & firstDataRow & ":I" & lastDataRow).FillDown
```

*) *As mentioned above, help states only:*

> "Fills down from the top cell or cells in the specified range to the bottom of the range. The contents and formatting of the cell or cells in the top row of a range are copied into the rest of the rows in the range."