Why does FillDown of Excel VBA use contents of the cell above when being called from a Range containing one cell?
I have a Excel Sheet that contains column headers in Row 1 and different formulas in Row 2.
To dynamically fill in the formulas based on the sheet's length I created a macro that extends the formulas to the last row using the "FillDown" function. However, I noticed that whenever my sheet is of length 1 (Meaning, Only Row 2 holds values) the FillDown function won't behave as expected as it will overwrite my formulas in Row 2 with the contents of Row 1 (the headers).
I then started to simplify my macro to the bare minimum and the behaviour still remains. Whenever you use a Sheet1 that has a arbitrary String in Row 1, and a formula in Row 2 below. The following macro will overwrite Row 2 with the contents of Row 1, despite the fact that Row 1 is never referenced in the macro.
Sub asdf()
    col = 1
    row = 2
    Set ws= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(row, col), ws.Cells(row, col)).FillDown
End Sub

Hereby I also noticed, that the placement (Row/Col) of the affected cell doesn't matter. Whenever the Range is only one cell large, it will overwrite any content in the cell with the contents of the cell above it.
I expected that the macro would either

do nothing, since Row 2 is already filled with its contents, and the FillDown only involves one cell.
re-write the contents of Row 2 into Row 2, having practically no effect.

Has anyone an idea why this would happen?
(Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2308 Build 16.0.16731.20542) 32-bit )
Edit: Just for clarification: The behavior of the FillDown Function is correct when we specify the cell range to be Row 2 to end in Row 3. The issue I observed is exclusively when we only define the range to be 1 cell/row wide. Then, instead of using the cell contents of the specified range, it defaults to the top cell.
Edit2: Replaced "Table" with sheet, as to not confuse it with Excel Table features.
Edit3: Made the macro more readable, replaced "Sheet" with "ws". The behaviour remains.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.filldown
Explicitly says "Fills down from the top cell or cells in the specified range to the bottom of the range. The contents and formatting of the cell or cells in the top row of a range are copied into the rest of the rows in the range."

Wouldn't this imply that it would start from the cell in the specified range? Because since we define a specific cell range, it would need to start at Row 2 and extend it to Row 2.
Edit: I don't see why the top cell (column header) would be relevant in this case. I also observed that the code behaves as expected when one changes the filldown range, such that it starts at Row 2 and ends in Row 3. The issue I observed is exclusively for the case where only one cell is involved.

You mentioned "table" - is that an Excel table? If so selecting any cell within it effectively selects the table itself

I should also say that I've ceased being surprised at unexpected behaviours in Office products these days - sorry, I've become old and cynical through bitter experience

No worries, I share your experience, but i remain curious if I have missed a relevant detail in my recent macro.
Also: Sorry about the confusion, I did not mean to refer to a "table" in the sense of an excel table (poor choice of words on my side). I refer to a normal Sheet, which is accessed using a VBA range. I will adapt the description accordingly.

No apology necessary.  The fact it isn't a Table makes this all the stranger. I will be snooping aournd tyring to find an explanation in my spare time so in the meantime good luck - I hope someone else comes by.
I don't know if it's relevant but Sheet is a reserved word - you could try changing the name of that variable and see if that makes any difference

Thank you! I tried changing the sheet variable name, but this doesn't seem to have an effect. But good point, about the reserved words. I also tested whether the behavior is exclusive to the column headers (row 1). But the placement of the cell doesn't seem to matter. It will overwrite the cell's content with whatever is above it.

For (many) years, the behavior of FillDown on a single cell has remained consistent, as you've noted. Is this behavior a software bug or an intended outcome? It's anyone's guess.

Previously - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62347688/478884
